# Pass parameter to Spring controller using @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a jsp that has an input field and a button. I should pass the input value to controller. My controller calls a REST API and get the response. Here the controller works fine.

search-menu.jsp

```
  <input  id="txt-menu-search" name="txt-menu-search" type="text"
                        class="form-control input-sm"/>

            <button class="btn btn-primary input-sm" id="btn-menu-search"><span><i
                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span></button>
```

SearchMenuController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search-menu/{searchItem}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public ModelAndView generateSearchItem(@PathVariable String searchItem ) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("search-results");
    // modelAndView.addObject("searchItem", searchItem);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String getItemUrl = SendStringBuilds.sendString(baseUrl, searchItemNameUrl, searchItem);

    ServerResponseMessage searchItemResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(getItemUrl, ServerResponseMessage.class);
    modelAndView.addObject("it", searchItemResponse.getData());
    modelAndView.addObject("test", searchItem);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This controller works when I change the URL. But it does not get the input value for path variable.
The Ajax in the search-menu.jsp is as follows.

```
<script>
    $("#btn-menu-search").click(function () {
        var searchKey = $("#txt-menu-search").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/web-selfcare/search-menu/'+searchKey,
            success: function (result) {
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Tell me how to map the input to the controller.

Comment: do you have request mapping for controller class?

Comment: is this script executed when the dom is ready? if yes could you please provide the output for console.log(searchkey); could you also explain in what way you need to change the url to make it work?

Comment: try to debug with firebug or any developer tool exactly what problem you are getting when firing ajax request .

Comment: @ Tommy Schmidt When I click the button it navigates to the same page.url is http://localhost:8080/web-selfcare/search-menu/?txt-menu-search=a.I want url to be http://localhost:8080/web-selfcare/search-menu/a

Comment: @D.Dev  check your java script code its not sending value correctly .

Comment: is the button inside a `<form>`? what is the output for console.log(searchkey);?

Comment: Yes,button is inside the form tags.And firebug gives following error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<<'
http://localhost:8080/web-selfcare/resources/js/registerandlogin.js
Line 112

Comment: try to add type="button" to the button to prevent it from submitting the form. you should prob. edit your question and include the form tag as well as the line with the firebug error.

Comment: @D.Dev Can you paste hare the `Line 112` of `registerandlogin.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question lacks some details. But the following could be possible causes

### Your search text includes `.` character.

By default the path variable regex of spring looks like `[^.]*`. which means anything but `period`. Hence if your searchText contains that character you should consider changing your path variable regex using `/{searchItem:.*}`

### Your controller have another method that matches.

If you have another controller method that could possibly match the URI, that other method might have been called instead. For example, if there is a  `RequestMapping` that takes `/search-menu/abc` and the search key is `abc`

### Search key was empty in the first place

The last possibility (and you should check out this first) is if the search key is correct. You can do this easily by looking at the network tab of the inspection tool available in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that the button is inside a form (as pointed out by the OP in comments) i think the problem is that the button submits the form instead of executing the ajax. This would also explain why the request includes get params instead of the disired path params.

This can be fixed by adding `type="button"` to the button.

However the question lacks some information, so this could be wrong.